# VBA : Having trouble putting a value filter on my pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table, threshold

So what I am trying to do is filtering the MEMBERS which have a value greater than > 5000 (threshhold of 5000) using VBA
But weirdly, it's not working..

Any type of solution is welcome !

Here is my code :

```
Sub Filterthreshhold()

Dim PSheet As Worksheet, DSheet As Worksheet, PCache As PivotCache, pvt As PivotTable, PRange As Range, lastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, pvtField  As PivotField, threshhold As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Prestations")

'Define Data Range

lastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="PoolPivotTable")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table

Set pvt = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PoolPivotTable")

Sheets("PivotTable").Name = "MEC"


'Insert Filter Fields

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PoolPivotTable").PivotFields("CODE")
.Orientation = xlPageField
.Position = 1
End With

'Insert Row Fields

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PoolPivotTable").PivotFields("PROV")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PoolPivotTable").PivotFields("MEMBRE")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PoolPivotTable").PivotFields("PAYEE")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 3
End With

'Insert Data Fields

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PoolPivotTable").PivotFields("SommeDeSANTE")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlSum
.Position = 1
.NumberFormat = "#,###.##"
.Name = "Santé"
End With

'Threshold

pvt.ClearAllFilters

Set pvtField = pvt.PivotFields("Sum of Santé")

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PoolPivotTable").PivotFields("MEMBRE")
pvtField.PivotFilters.Add xlValueIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo, Value1:=5000
End With

'I have also tried .PivotFilters.Add2
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please mention the error description and the line at which the error occurs.

Comment: Does the "members" field contain numeric values?

Comment: Hi, thank your for your responses, as for the code, no error code appears, I run the code and the pivot table is created, but the filter is not applied.                                              The members field contains values from 0 to 13 !

Comment: OK I was confused by the With block which does nothing there...  You seem to have two different names for the field though?  "Sum of Sante" vs "SommeDeSANTE" earier?  And you have `On Error Resume Next` so you'll never know when your code hits a problem.  Comment that out and see what happens.

Comment: @TimWilliams Finally worked Thanks ! turns out there were a couple errors hidden by the `On Error Resume Next` .. rookie mistake!

Answer (score 0):

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PoolPivotTable").PivotFields("MEMBRE")
pvtField.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:= xlValueIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo, DataField:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PoolPivotTable"). _
        PivotFields("Sum of Santé"),Value1:=5000
End With
```

You might be missing the data field of your sum